# Scrollable JPanel to return to the top of the panel after an event

Tags: java, scrollbar

I have a scrollable JPanel which accepts other JPanels dynamicly.

```
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

    jPanel2 = new JPanel();// container jPanel

    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.pink);
    jPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    scrollPane.add(jPanel2);

    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

the program can add and delete JPanels to this JPanel and it will scroll. when the JPanel is getting bigger and you add another JPanel i would like the Container JPanel to have the scroll bar at the top.

Comment: Don't use ScrollPane, use JScrollPane. Then don't add components to a JScrollPane, but set its viewportView. You can then use scrollRectToVisible (on the component been used as the view) to move back to 0x0 position